# Improve WCF service performance

Tags: c#, wcf, performance, iis-7.5

My company owns a server with 24 cores and a lot a RAM inside. The OS is Windows 2008 R2 SP1. I deployed on this server a WCF application, hosted in IIS. On the same server I installed a multithreaded client which calls one of the WCF service, as often as possible. I encountered a bottleneck : all the cores on the server are used, but at a very low level, so the CPU consumption doesn't exceed 10 %. My WCF service is configured like this :

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="myBehavior" name="...">
    <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="myBinding" bindingNamespace="..." contract="..."/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="myBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="200" maxConcurrentSessions="200" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="myBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxConnections="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" portSharingEnabled="false" transactionFlow="false" listenBacklog="2147483647">
      <security mode="None">
        <message clientCredentialType="None"/>
        <transport protectionLevel="None" clientCredentialType="None"/>
      </security>
      <reliableSession enabled="false"/>
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="204800" maxArrayLength="204800" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

My service has also the following attributes : InstanceContextMode.Single and ConcurrencyMode.Multiple. Did anyone encounter a similar problem ? I searched the solution for days, but I didn't find it yet :(

Thank you in advance !

Comment: What makes you think that the CPU usage is the constraint?

Comment: On a server with "only" eight cores, I get almost the same performance as on the server I mentioned on my post...

Comment: @schglurps if you get the same perf on 8 vs 24, that pretty much proves it is unrelated to CPU

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how you're measuring the performance bottleneck but no matter how many client calls you generate, the service will only handle 200 calls at a time. The netTcpBinding is uses sessions so the throttle there is the `maxConcurrentSessions="200"` setting. You've configured the service as a multi-threaded singleton which is limited to 200 simultaneous calls by the `maxConcurrentCalls="200"` setting. The CPU load will also depend on how much work is performed during each call and whether it is IO bound or not. Review the [serviceThrottling element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731379.aspx) documentation and try increasing both settings to see if your throughput improves.

If your sevice implementation allows, I would recommend you try configuring the service with `InstanceContextMode.PerSession` and `ConcurrencyMode.Single` to compare throughput with your current configuration. IIS 7x hosts WCF services using the Windows Process Activation Service (WAS). WAS is designed to handle concurrency. A singleton configuration negates the value of using WAS.